# Find all files and list all attributes in terminal

Tags: terminal, find, pipe, ls

I can list all test.txt files on RHEL terminal using

```
sudo find / -iname 'list.txt'
```

If there is a file `/media/my/list.txt` I can run

```
sudo ls -la /media/my/list.txt
```

to get the attributes. How can I pipe all results from the first command to the second command to see the attributes of all files from the first command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
sudo ls -la $(sudo find / -iname 'list.txt' | xargs)
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a pipe.

Since you are using RHEL you probably have GNU `find` which (among others) provides a `-ls` action

```
sudo find / -iname 'list.txt' -ls
```

Otherwise, [POSIXly](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html)

```
sudo find / -iname 'list.txt' -exec ls -l {} +
```

Comment: This is not about GNU find... `find -ls` has been introduced by SunOS-3.x in 1986 and `find -exec +` has been introduced by David Korn at AT&T in 1988. GNU find even was late with implementing this...